# Как вызвать переменную с другого файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

решил сделать экономику в дискорд боте но столкнулся с проблемой при попытке вызвать переменную с DataBase.py в main.py выходит ошибка: **NameError: name 'money' is not defined** Вот код запроса переменной

```py
from DataBase import *
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM main where id={msg.author.id}")
    if cursor.fetchone() == None:
        InsertValues(msg.author, msg.author.id)
        conn.commit()
        print(f"{msg.author}") #если нет в бд
    else:
        pass
    print(LoadAccount(msg.author.id)[money]) #запрос к бд
```

А также файл DataBase:

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
def InsertValues(val1, val2):
    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO main VALUES ("{val1}", {val2}, 2000, 2000)')
    conn.commit()
def CreateDB():
    cursor.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"(
    "name"TEXT,
    "id"INT,
    "money"INT,
    "XP"INT)''')
    conn.commit()
def LoadAccount(member):
    for row in cursor.execute(f"SELECT name,money,XP FROM main where id={member}"):
        global money
        name = row[0]
        money = row[1]
        xp = row[2]
```

Comment: дубликатов, наверно, вагон.

Answer (score 1):

**Основной файл**:

```
from DataBase import *

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await bot.process_commands(msg)

    cursor.execute(f"SELECT name FROM main where id={msg.author.id}")
    if cursor.fetchone() == None:
        InsertValues(msg.author, msg.author.id)
        conn.commit()
        print(f"{msg.author}") # если пользователя нету в БД
    else:
        pass

    print(LoadAccount(msg.author.id)) # отправляем запрос к БД
```

**Файл DataBase**:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

def InsertValues(val1, val2):
    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO main VALUES ("{val1}", {val2}, 2000, 2000)')
    conn.commit()

def CreateDB():
    cursor.execute(f'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "main"(
    "name"TEXT,
    "id"INT,
    "money"INT,
    "XP"INT)''')
    conn.commit()

def LoadAccount(member):
    for row in cursor.execute(f"SELECT name,money,XP FROM main where id={member}"):
        name = row[0]
        money = row[1]
        xp = row[2]
    return money
```